# Run-Time Error 1004: Excel VBA is unable to find a file to open

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to run a VBA program to compare a Bill of Materials(BOM) and a list of parts, but am having trouble opening the files to do so. I get a Run-time Error '1004' on "Workbooks.Open (BomName)".  The files are in the same folder. Any Advice?

```
    '1. Imput BomName
     Dim BomName As String
    BomName = InputBox("Enter BOM to check")
        If BomName = "" Then
            Exit Sub
         Else
            'continue program
        End If

    '2 Open BomName File & Vantage Parts File
     Workbooks.Open (BomName)
     Workbooks.Open ("Part Last Cost Demand wMin Qty.xlsx")
```

Comment: read MSDN documentation, it's very easy to understand: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try typing the full path name to the BOM workbook such as: C:\workbookname.xlsx  I would also recommend, since they're in the same folder, using a string variable to represent the folder location.  Then, all you need to do is `workbooks.open(path & BomName)`

Comment: Thank you! Adding the path variable worked like a charm! :)

Comment: Great!  Glad to help!